# I can't parse the following lines of android(/java) code

Tags: android

I'm working my way threw a couple of books on android programing with a friend of mine (So I guess you'd kind of call this homework?) We have come across code segments like the following example a number of times and I have never fully understood the segments, just mindlessly used it. Would someone have the time to break the example into a couple of lines NOT held together with the "dot" operator? I've tried a bunch of times and I'm pulling my hair out over it and I'm old enough that I don't have much hair left.

```
View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
    .inflate(R.layout.some_dialog,  null);


return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(v)
    .setTitle(R.string.some_dumb_title)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)   // null can be On Click Listener
    .create();
```

Maybe a pointer to some web pages that uses simple lines of code to do the work. I know the way it is written is more efficent but  seeing it laid out as seperate lines would make it much easier to understand and more important, easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Activity a = getActivity();
LayoutInflater inflater = a.getLayoutInflater();
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_dialog,  null);


AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(v);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.some_dumb_title);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);   // null can be On Click Listener
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
return dialog;
```

Both of these examples chain methods together since we don't care about the references in between, we care about the final product. If your code works well, and you know what you're doing, chaining is convenient. For debugging purposes, don't chain methods, the stack trace will not be as helpful (consider what happens is `getLayoutInflater()` returned `null` when chaining methods.

It is worth noting though, that for the `AlertDialog.Builder` example, each of its methods returns the same `AlertDialog.Builder` Object, whereas in the first example, you are getting a lot of different Objects in an attempt to inflate your given View.

Comment: Thanks MUCH: I am checking your offering now. If it works I will defiantly come back and select this as a correct answer - Joe

Comment: Worked great. Already figured out I needed the semi-colons. This answers a LOT of questions that have been bugging me for months. I accepted the answer, and hit +1. 
Thanks once again - Joe

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to create an `AlertDialog`.  If we [follow what the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) says about it, we arrive at the following:

```
View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
.inflate(R.layout.some_dialog,  null);
```

This roughly translates to:

- Get an activity on the current instance or super class
- With that activity, get its layout inflater
- With that layout inflater, inflate it with the arguments `R.layout.some_dialog`, `null`.

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
.setView(v)
.setTitle(R.string.some_dumb_title)
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)   // null can be On Click Listener
.create();
```

This roughly translates to:

- Get a new builder, passing along the activity of the current instance or super class
- Then, with that builder, set the view
- With the same builder, set the title to `R.string.some_dumb_title`
- With the same builder, set a positive button with the parameters `android.R.string.ok`, `null`
- With the same builder, invoke `create`, thus creating the `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Thanks Makoto: Your explanation, coupled with 'A--C"'s code snippets, answered a bunch of questions I've been pounding my head over for a long while. I did add a +1 to your answer.